# How to patch a file that resides in /Applications (patch can't find file to patch at input line)?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, unix

I am trying to patch 5 files within an Mac application bundle using the Terminal `patch` command. The files to be patch are specified using an absolute file path (the file name and path start with a slash).

The output when running `$ sudo patch -i ~/custom.patch` is:

```
can't find file to patch at input line 3
Perhaps you should have used the -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|--- /Applications/Xyz.app/Contents/Resources/dashboard.js
|+++ /Applications/Xyz.app/Contents/Resources/dashboard.js
--------------------------
File to patch: ^C
```

I have verified that the file /Applications/Xyz.app/Contents/Resources/dashboard.js does exist using at the specified file path using the `ls` command.

Regression:

1. Tried to run the patch command from root folder using `$ cd /`
2. Tried to run the patch command from root folder with the first slash removed, that results in an almost identical result:

---

```
can't find file to patch at input line 3
Perhaps you should have used the -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|--- Applications/Xyz.app/Contents/Resources/dashboard.js
|+++ Applications/Xyz.app/Contents/Resources/dashboard.js
--------------------------
File to patch: ^C
```

How can multiple files within a Mac OS X Application bundle be patched using `patch`?

Comment: @grgarside The difference is `/Applications/` versus `Applications/`

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that you are not specifying the p option.

From the [manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/patch.1.html) for patch:

```
For example, supposing the file name  in  the  patch file was

  /u/howard/src/blurfl/blurfl.c

setting -p0 gives the entire file name unmodified, -p1 gives

  u/howard/src/blurfl/blurfl.c

without the leading slash, -p4 gives

  blurfl/blurfl.c

and  not  specifying  -p  at  all just gives you

  blurfl.c.

Whatever you end up with is looked for either in the current directory,
or the directory specified by the -d option.
```

So the command should be something like:

```
patch -p0 <custom.patch
```

or you could specify the directory to which the patch should be applied:

```
patch -d /path/to/dir <custom.patch
```

Comment: `-p -d` look promising when all to be patch files are in the same folder. `-p` is not an answer, as my wish is to specify absolute path file locations from within the patch file. The wish is to patch different files  at different absolute path locations.

Comment: for `-d`that is true. the parameter `-p` works with the file names found in the patch file. so with the `-p0` you should be able to specify absolute file paths